# Is there any way to update files on deployed angular application directly without building?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm

I have created one angular application and deployed it on production environment using

```
npm run build --prod --base -href
```

command. Now as per new requirement we have to change few HTML and TypeScript static file data.

As it is bundled deployed app so I am not sure how to update them without building it again.

Is there any way to update those data directly on deployed site?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Typescript gets compiled to javascript at static compilation time, the output gets minified and bundled before getting served. Without redeployment you can change only dynamic data that your client is referencing, but not internal HTML or script files.